# How can you distinguish modular exponentiation from random?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, random, cryptography, totient-function

> Let $N$ be the product of two primes and let $P$ be the smallest prime larger than $N$.
>
> - Let the algorithm $R(N,s)$ return $s^{1/P} \pmod{N}$.
> - Let the algorithm $\widehat{R}(N,s)$ pick a random element $u\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}^*_N$ and return it.
>
> Show that you can distinguish $R$ from $\widehat{R}$ with significant advantage; that is, show that there is an efficient (potentially **probabilistic**) algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ for which
>
> $$\left|\Pr_{N,s}\left[\mathcal{A}(N, s, R(N,s) ) = 1\right] - \Pr_{N,s}\left[\mathcal{A}(N,s,\widehat{R}(N,s))=1\right]\right| \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Note: This is a homework question, so I would like hints for how to become unstuck, not full solutions.

So far, I have tried to discover what behavior the map $\square\mapsto \square^{1/P}$ has, but with little luck. I believe the maps $\square\mapsto \square^{P}$ and $\square \mapsto \square^{1/P}$ (modulo $N$) are always permutations since $\varphi(N)$ and $P$ are necessarily coprime. 
This is a confusing result, because it suggests that $R(N,\cdot)$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$, which I would think would make it hard to distinguish from random.

I am also trying to determine whether $s^{1/P}$ "leaks" important information about $s$, perhaps parity or something. I believe it does, but I am not sure where.

Suggestions for where to look next?

Comment: Finding P is easy, so you can put s = 2^p.

Comment: This question reminds me of chicken sexing. Have you made a table of values of R(N,s). The pattern may be more intuitive than you think.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have generated some tables, but the pattern isn't clear to me yet. I've looked at differences, relationships between p/q and so on. 
P Q N : first few (s,r) pairs
3 3 9 : [(1, 1), (2, 8), (4, 1), (5, 8), (7, 1), (8, 8)]

3 5 15 :        [(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4), (7, 7), (8, 8), (11, 11)]

3 7 21 :        [(1, 1), (2, 11), (4, 16), (5, 17), (8, 8), (10, 19)]

3 11 33 :       [(1, 1), (2, 8), (4, 31), (5, 26), (7, 13), (8, 17)]

3 13 39 :       [(1, 1), (2, 32), (4, 10), (5, 5), (7, 37), (8, 8)]

3 17 51 :       [(1, 1), (2, 32), (4, 4), (5, 20), (7, 40), (8, 26)]

Comment: Sorry, the formatting didn't work on the last comment. Here is a better-formatted table:  http://pastebin.com/2XVJfNEt

I'm wondering if I made a mistake while making the table, or if I've just missed the pattern?